# time difference in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to get the time passed from the moment i posted a thing till now . I am defining a method in my model class :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :comment , :presence => true

def time_past
 DateTime.now - self.created_at

end
end
```

Here is the error :

irb(main):001:0> Post.first.time_past
TypeError: expected numeric or date
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1252:in `minus_without_duration'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb:98:in`-'
    from /home/badescuga/proiecte/soundplace/app/models/post.rb:5:in `time_past'
    from (irb):1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use self.created_at, instead of #{created_at}

Comment: i've corrected the code posted as you told me but it still doesn't work . in the edit you can also see the error retrieved

Comment: That is because you are using `DateTime`. It gives you an object of type `DateTime`. `created_at`, however, is `Time`. Try my code snippet and it should work.

Comment: Ahh sorry i haven't seen the difference regarding Time and DateTime , sorry

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with this method.

```
def time_since_creation
  Time.now - created_at
end
```